# Why select CAST(b'11' AS DEC); equals 3?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql> select CAST(b'11' AS DEC);
+--------------------+
| CAST(b'11' AS DEC) |
+--------------------+
|                  3 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

BUT:

```
mysql> select CAST(a'11' AS DEC);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''11' AS DEC)' at line 1
```

WHY? It's so strange. Thanks.

---

It seems that my question isn't clear enough. I make my apology here.
`b'11'` doesn't equal to  `a'11'`. And there is absolutely some kind of type cast there.
And my question is, why `b'11'` is equal to `3` in binary notation, after typecasting. `b'11'` doesn't look like a binary number.

Comment: Presumably binary has something to do with it...

Comment: "b'11'" != "a'11'" ...

Comment: `And my question is, why b'11' is equal to 3 in binary notation, after typecasting. b'11' doesn't look like a binary number.`  Say what?  It absolutely looks like a binary number.

Answer (score 10):

`b'11'` is `11` in [binary notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number), so it's 3 in standard, decimal one.